# Response Code 415 (makehttpRequest method)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, http, http-post, xmlhttprequest

estoy obteniendo este error

"message": "Response code 415 (Unsupported Media Type)"

trato de obtener el response

```
  async loginPost(){
  const param = JSON.stringify({
    grant_type:"password",
    username: process.env.EMAIL,
    password: process.env.PASS,
  });
  const response = await makeHttpRequest(
    process.env.URL_LOGIN,
      null,
    "POST",
    param
  );
  const responseBody2 = prettyPrintJSON(JSON.parse(response.body));
  console.log("Response " + responseBody2)
```

}

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: que hace la funcion `makeHttpRequest`?